# Mono 2.10 dislike mysql for linux?

Tags: mysql, mono

I grabbed [mysql-connector-net-6.5.4-noinstall.zip](http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Net/mysql-connector-net-6.5.4-noinstall.zip) for '.NET & Mono'. I used it in MSVS and had no problems. Trying to run the binary on linux with mono 2.10 i get an error about the mysql dll being invalid. When looking in mono develop I can actually brows the DLL. When i try to build the compiler throws a fit claiming the name is invalid

When running the binary built on windows i get this exception instead

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
```

How do i get this to work? Note: I built it under 3.5 and the server i plan on using only has mono 2.6 so i cant upgrade to .NET 4

-edit-

I checked what the server said and i got this exception. Note the mysql.data.dll is in the same directory.

```
** (MySqlTest.exe:28256): WARNING **: The following assembly referenced from /root/apps/MySqlTest/MySqlTest.exe could not be loaded:
     Assembly:   MySql.Data    (assemblyref_index=2)
     Version:    6.5.4.0
     Public Key: c5687fc88969c44d
The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of the executing assembly (/root/apps/MySqlTest/).

** (MySqlTest.exe:28256): WARNING **: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh ^&*(), they packaged it wrong. They built the dll with a case sensitive filename and lowercase the dll name before ziping it. Renaming to `MySql.Data.dll` solves it.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide more info about the root of the problem. What packaging? Did you report the bug upstream? If you do this, you may save tons of other people's time if they run into the same issue.

Comment: @knocte: I didn't report it nor want to (too lazy, dont know where it is ATM). But the package is their official link as mentioned in the question. Their mysql connector section, under '.NET & Mono'